# ¿Por qué en Postman retorna bien y en JS con Fetch no?

Tags: javascript, api, fetch, postman

estoy trabajando con una API y tuve que empezar a investigar porque utiliza autorización OAUTH 2.0, lo cuál está siendo un problema para mi. Es una API del estado por ende normal que necesite esta seguridad.
Siguiendo el manual de conexión brindando por el ente estatal, logro obtener el token desde postman y puedo realizar diversas consultas, el problema es cuando lo hago en JS con fetch.

```
  function getToken() {
  fetch(
    "https://mvdapi-auth.montevideo.gub.uy/auth/realms/pci/protocol/openid-connect/token",
    {
      method: "POST",
      body: {
        client_id: key,
        client_secret: secret,
        grant_type: "client_credentials",
      },
      headers: { 
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
    }
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
}
```

Cosas a tener en cuenta:

1. El eror que me arroja es este:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Ahora, como punto 2, me gustaría recalcar que en el content type estoy poniendo el x-www-form-urlencoded, aún así, nada...
3. En postman:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
4. Los headers en Postman:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por último, si intento poner Host y poner mi dirección localhost de mi página web, tampoco soluciona el problema.

Comment: Si tienes instalado la app de postman, a la derecha, hay un símbolo `</>` que al hacer click se expande y puedes exportar el código de la petición que estás haciendo de manera exacta a cualquier lenguaje. Selecciona `javascript - fetch` y prueba hacer la petición con el código que te genera postman. Si te sirve en postman, debe servirte en javascript el código que postman te genera.

Comment: Creo que fetch no acepta un objeto directo en el body... creo que deberías es enviarlo como json... `body: JSON.stringify({ client_id: .... })`

Comment: Muchas gracias @JaimeMenéndez, copie el método desde Postman y ahora si funciona el fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos opciones para intentar. Como estás enviando los datos como JSON, el encabezado actual no es compatible, prueba a cambiarlo por `application/json`:

```
function getToken() {
  fetch(
    "https://mvdapi-auth.montevideo.gub.uy/auth/realms/pci/protocol/openid-connect/token",
    {
      method: "POST",
      body: {
        client_id: key,
        client_secret: secret,
        grant_type: "client_credentials",
      },
      headers: { 
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
}
```

Si no funciona, entonces crea un objeto [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) para agregar cada campo:

```
function getToken() {
  // Crea el objeto
  let formData = new FormData();
  // Agrega la información necesaria
  formData.append('client_id', key);
  formData.append('client_secret', secret);
  formData.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
  fetch(
    "https://mvdapi-auth.montevideo.gub.uy/auth/realms/pci/protocol/openid-connect/token",
    {
      method: "POST",
      // Envía el objeto como cuerpo de la petición
      body: formData,
      headers: { 
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
    }
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
}
```